# Why reading is done at random speeds when using createReadStream (file reading) on local node?

Tags: node.js

I am using `createReadStream` api to read huge data from a file.
Sometimes it takes 7 seconds to read while sometimes it takes 30 seconds to read.
I would like to understand why it is taking more time to read the same file with same data in some instances while it is taking less time in few instances. Why it is not fixed time as I am reading the same file with same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible reasons:

**1. Disk caching.**  The OS has a disk cache and uses it when it knows it is safe to use the cache.  This will often make the first read of some data slower (because it's being read directly from the disk) and later reads of the same data faster (if the OS thinks it can be successfully cached and is not too large to be cached and it stays in the cache).

**2. Nodejs event loop unpredictability.**  Reading a large set of data will necessarily require reading many blocks of the file, each one of the read operations will go through the nodejs event loop.  If there are other events also being inserted into the event loop, the disk-read-related events may sometimes have to wait their turn.

**3. Garbage collector unpredictability.**  If you're dealing with large amounts of data (even if not all in memory at once), you may be creating lots of objects in the nodejs heap, many of which needs to be garbage collected.  Eventually, the garbage collector will have to run and may introduce a bit of a pause in the execution of your code.  If this happens multiple times during an operation, this could become noticeable.

**4. Disk busyness variability.**  A disk read/write head (assuming this is a spinning disk and the OS is reading from the actual disk) can only be on one track at a time.  If it's busy reading something else that the OS asked it to read, your request may have to wait for some prior requests to finish.  This wouldn't typically add up to many seconds, but it can lead to some variability.  As an example of a worst case, the OS could be running a defrag operation on your hard drive which your disk operations would have to interleave with.

**5. OS/CPU busyness.**  If the OS or CPU is busy doing something else, your app may not be getting full cycles to run.

**6. Nodejs threadpool busy.**  Nodejs uses a threadpool with a default size of 4 for disk operations.  If you happen to have multiple disk operations (or other operations that use the thread pool) in flight at the same time and max out the threadpool, then your operation may have to wait for some previous operation to finish before you get allocated a thread to run your disk operation in. The size of the threadpool is customizable, but making it larger than the number of actual CPU cores you have is probably not helpful.